# オブジェクト指向によるthisの使い方

Tags: java

現在、MainクラスとPersonクラスを生成し、`this.name` で名前をコンストラクタに設定し、出力するプログラムを作っています。そこで、`this` について質問があります。

以下のコードでインスタンスを生成したときに `this.name = name` と定義し、`System.out.println(name);` と書くことでAくんとBくんの名前を出力できますが、 `println(name)` の所を `println(this.name)` と入力しても、同様にAくんとBくんの名前が出力されます。

`this.name` と書くのと、`name` と書き出力するのでは、なにか違いはあるのでしょうか？

---

**Main.java:**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main (String args[]) {
        Person person1 = new Person("Aくん"); 
        person1.hello();
        Person person2 = new Person("Bくん");
        person2.hello();
    }
}
```

**Person.java:**

```
class Person{
    public String name;

    public Person(String name) {
        this.name = name;    
    }

    public void hello() {
        System.out.println(name);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `this.name`と書くのと、`name`と書き出力するのでは、なにか違いはあるのでしょうか？

**`hello()` メソッドの中では** どちらも同じものです。つまり、違いはありません。

---

`name` のようなものを単純名(simple name)、 `this.name` のようなものを修飾名(qualified name)と呼びます。

同名の変数が存在しない場合、その変数は単純名で参照することができます。

他方、同名の変数が複数存在する場合、単純名で参照できるのはそのうちどれかひとつで、それ以外は単純名では参照できなくなります(shadowing)。shadowingされた変数は修飾名で参照する必要があります。
このときの、単純名で参照できるのはどれなのかは仕様([6.4.1. Shadowing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se18/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.4.1))で決まっています。

今回の例で言うと、`name` という名前は、

- フィールド
- コンストラクタの仮引数

の2つで用いられています。

従って、コンストラクタでは、次のルールで変数を参照することになります。

- 単純名`name`は仮引数を指す(前述の仕様により)
- フィールドはshadowingされる
- shadowingされたフィールドを参照するためには修飾名(今回の場合は `this.name`)を用いる必要がある

これに対し、 `hello()` メソッドでは(コンストラクタと異なり) `name` はフィールドのみを指すので、そのまま単純名 `name` でフィールドを参照できます。

Answer (score 1):

ここの `this.name`

```
public Person(String name) {
    this.name = name;    
}
```

は、コンストラクターの引数として与えられるローカル変数 `name` と、フィールド変数として定義された

```
public String name;
```

の `name` とを区別して、フィールド変数の `name` であることを明示するためのものです。

要するに、this（このインスタンスの）`name` ですよ、という意味です。

一方、

```
public void hello() {
    System.out.println(name);
}
```

こちらにおいては、引数としてローカル変数の name が存在するわけではないので、`this.` を付けて明示する必要がないだけです。実質、モノとしては `this.name` と同じものです。

```
public Person(String name) {
    this.name = name;    
}
```

の（`this.` なしの）`name` だけが、引数から与えられるローカル変数として、他とは違う実体のものです。